# I want give 50% left border of my div

Tags: css

Here I am trying to give 50% Of left SIDE OF BORDER OF MY DIV 
BUT NOT ABEL TO MANAGE . i HAVE THREE DIV WITH SAME CLASS BUT FACING ISSUE .

```
.testinomila-post{

    width: 350px;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 60px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-left: 20px;
    padding: 40px;
    list-style: none;
}

.testinomila-post:before {
  content : "";
  position: absolute;
  left    : 0;
  bottom  : 0;
  height  : 1px;
  width   : 50%;  /* or 100px */
  border-left:5px solid magenta;
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJxm6.png)

Comment: Please provide the `html` and your expected result

Comment: Please do not write in CAPS. Also, I understand not everyone is a native speaker, but "give 50% of left side of border of my div" is not comprehensible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you try to make something like this ?

```css
.testinomila-post{
  position: relative;
    width: 350px;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 60px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-left: 20px;
    padding: 40px;
    list-style: none;
}

.testinomila-post:before {
  content : "";
  position: absolute;
  left    : 0;
  bottom  : 0;
  height  : 100%;
  width   : 1;  /* or 100px */
  border-left: 1px solid magenta;
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="testinomila-post">

</div>
<div class="testinomila-post">

</div>
<div class="testinomila-post">

</div>
```

Just add `position: relative` on your parent element and change `border-left`, `width` and add `display: block`

Comment: Can i use this with left border, I am getting issue when I am trying border:left, and no background of parent div

Comment: I Need left border not bottom any help

Comment: Post a screen of what you want to do please, it's not clear

Comment: added but no result

Comment: cyril@ i changed the border-left, but its not showing any result can you help this regarding this

Comment: @sanjay check my snippet

Comment: Cyril Beeckman@I see that its still working with bottom-border. not working with lef .please check this

Comment: Cyril Beeckman @@please run code snippet it's still left  bottom side . please check to run this code

Comment: @sanjay Just post a screen of what you want, really

Comment: Cyril Beeckman@please let me know how can integrate  right border also

Comment: @sanjay copy rule ::before and make ::after, change border-left to border-right and left:0 to right: 0